# Making subclasses from Custom Class in Kivy

Tags: python, class, kivy, subclass

Has anyone had any luck with Kivy in using subclasses of custom classes? It's been something that's been really giving me issues because I'd like to be able to use some polymorphism in order to simply some operations that are essentially the same.

When trying to use the typical method for creating a custom class using __init__ and super().__init__ there is always an error involving the styling of the base kivy class I am trying to inherit from when instantiating an instance of a subclass.

I've been able to get somewhere by using passing the __init__ and using the __new__ method with the custom class and it seems to be working well enough, but I'm sure its not a complete fix since I'm not able to make the Custom class a Layout like I originally intended.

This is an example of how I make the custom class using __init__:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(CustomClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

And this is an example of how I use __new__ instead:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    pass

def __new__(self, **kwargs):
    super(CustomClass, self).__new__(**kwargs)
```

And this is how I'm using the custom class:

```
class SubClass(CustomClass):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(SubClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**Update**

It seems like the issue was with the specific name of the class I was using for my super/sub classes. They conflicted with names already in the kivy library that I wasn't aware of

Comment: I'm not aware of any generic issue with using subclasses of custom classes in relation to Kivy. Can you give an example of the basic implementation not working?

Comment: @inclement Never mind. It seems like I was messing something up originally because I'm no longer able to reproduce the error